# Using jquery-datetimepicker.js with MVC EditorFor

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I've added XDSoft's jquery-datetimepicker from NuGet, but am having a lot of trouble getting it to render on views.

I ended up trying to cobble some instructions together from http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/ (the page for the package) and http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/a-jquery-ui-based-date-picker-for-asp.net-mvc-5.html (which is for the jquery-UI package, but has a lot more generalised help) but cannot for the life of me figure out where I'm going wrong.

In BundleConfig.cs, I've added:

```
    // datetime picker
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/datetime").Include(
        "~/Scripts/jquery.datetimepicker.js"));
    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/datetime").Include(
        "~/Content/jquery.datetimepicker.css"));
```

Then in _Layout.cshtml, I've added:

```
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/datetime")
```

and:

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/datetime")
```

For good measure, in troubleshooting, I've tried adding those directly into the view in question as well, which is based off of the template for a create view.

So my understanding, is that then all I must do, is to set the class on the control to be "datetime". This doesn't work (appears as a normal textbox).

I then also tried using `@Html.TextBoxFor()` instead, also to no avail. If I change the class to `xdsoft_datetimepicker` instead, it leaves an empty gap rather than creating a text box, but obviously still not what I want either.

Any pointers, or links to a **complete** tutorial (not so much assumed knowledge like https://cuteprogramming.wordpress.com/2015/08/29/jquery-plugins-xdsoft-datetimepicker-and-jssor-slider/, where it mentions adding a function, without saying where on earth I'm adding it or how) for showing a (browser agnostic) date-time picker for DateTime properties on the model would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have to attach the plugin to the element e.g $(someElement).datetimepicker({ ... });` Show your view.

Answer (score 0):

I also used `ref` from codeguru website that you used. Check your `js` and `css` files are loading correctly when debugging. If not, use direct link referencing in your `_Layout.cshtml` instead of bundling.